# JQuery addClass() that has a space in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

How can I use JQuery's `addClass` method to add a class that has a space in it? For example:

```
.list {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
}
```

I am trying to update/replace the inner html of a list inside an event handler, but when I do that all the CSS formatting goes away. I just need a way of putting it back, so I was going to use something like `$('#my_list').addClass('list list li')` but I don't know how to get it to recognize the `li` part. I've tried escaping the space, but no luck; passing it `'list list\ li'` doesn't do the trick, either.

Comment: classes can't contain spaces, so that's not an issue. `.list li` targets any LI elements inside `.list`

Comment: `li` is not a `class` it's `element`

Comment: `.list li` refers to an `<li>` element that is a descendant of an element with a class of `list`. Spaces aren't permitted in class names - you'd never try to add `list li` as a class.

Comment: Se [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who cleared this up for me. I knew the behavior of `.list li` but I didn't know how to express what it's called. I still don't know what you would call it, but I now know that 'a class with spaces in it' is not the proper term :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the class `list` to the `#my_list` and rest of the code it just css. once you add the `list` class to the `ul` element, it will automatically apply the `:hover` style for the child `li` elements

jQuery,

```
$('#my_list').addClass('list');
```

css,

```
.list {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
}
```

For more clear, in your code `list` is the only class you has. and `li` is not a class it is a `li` element inside the `ul` tag. and `li:hover` means hover effect of the `li` element

Answer (score 1):

`.list li` is not specifying a class with a space in it. That is selecting an `li` element that is somewhere in the structure underneath any element with the `list` class in it. It's hard to say exactly what you need to do without seeing how your HTML is structured and how much you're replacing. If you just replace the `li`s inside of your `.list` element then it will still work fine. If you're replacing the whole thing then just make sure you add the `list` class to the parent element that contains the `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `.list li` matches the following:

> Any `<li>` element that's a descendent of an element with the class `list`

It does not match an element with a class called `"list li"`. If you want to use some kind of spacer character in your classes use a hyphen:

```
.list-li:hover {
}
```

To add this class:

```
$(this).addClass('list-li')
```